# Python: redirect print output (stdout) to logging with multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, stdout, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a python class that use some other classes/modules developed by ourself.

We use some prints in each module to prompt some information to the user (logging is also used for more detailed information). 
The problem is that when (sub)modules are used by a 'master' class prints may become too many and hide the essential master's information. In my current application, the 'master' is a genetic algorithm, using a multiprocessing subclass (to run the cases) who also use some other subclasses (to run the non-python code, to define initialization data, ...). Each class print information that is pertinent to that class, while I only would like to display master's information.

I than tried to redirect sys.stdout and sys.stderr to logging. See hereafter my attempt on a simplified example.

**Called module**

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def send2disp(text) :
    print(text)
    return

def send2disp_mp(text) :
    workers = [Process(target=send2disp,args=(text+str(pi),)) for pi in range(2)]
    for ti in workers :
        ti.start()
    for ti in workers :
        ti.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

**Master script**

```
from test_print import send2disp,send2disp_mp #'test_print' is the module filename
import logging
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    send2disp('NoRedirection->OnStdout')

    logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',level=logging.DEBUG,filemode='w')
    logging.info('OnLog')

    fl = logging.getLoggerClass().root.handlers[0].stream

    sys.stdout = fl
    sys.stderr = fl    

    print('InScript->IsOnLog')

    send2disp('SubModule->IsOnLog')
    send2disp_mp('ShouldBeOnlog')
```

With the master script I define a log file and redirect stdout/stderr to it. I then call the two functions of the submodule:

- 'send2disp' works well and print outputs go to the log
- 'send2disp_mp', instead, keep sending print outputs to the stdout...the only difference being the use of multiprocessing, this is supposed to be the source of the issue.

How can I deal with redirecting stdout and multiprocessing? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the sys redirections only work for the current process.  Did you try to do the redirections inside the children processes ?

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue with python 2.7 and python 3.6, everything except `'NoRedirection->OnStdout'` is on the file

Comment: @CorentinLimier: I am using python 3.3.5.

Comment: Could you try : on a newer version of python ? Or moving the sys redirections inside the send2disp_mp function (or using decorator)

Comment: @CorentinLimier: and in case it may be important, it is a winpython install and I am running the script in windows powershell.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that's why I don't like the idea of redirecting the stdout or stderr. Maybe someone more informed will tell you that it is not a bad practice but I have the feeling that it is bad practice.

Comment: I would use logging everywhere or use the file parameter on the print function.

Comment: @CorentinLimier: I also tested on 3.4.4 with identical results. The followings are on stdout (last 2 should be on log...): 
`NoRedirection->OnStdout
ShouldBeOnlog0
ShouldBeOnlog1`